# Feels like you have seen this many times

Tags: visual

What are you looking at?

[image]

Hint

> It is a jumbled version with a missing letter

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It must be

> **The IBM logo**
>  [image]

The missing letter is

> The registered trademark ®
>  [image]